# SignalR asp.net core with flutter ArgumentNullException: IDX10000: not working on live server

Tags: asp.net, flutter, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

[image]signalr is working fine in my flutter app with asp.net core 3.1 on local server but its not working with live server.
flutter packge : signalr_netcore 1.2.3+1
Live server Error
HubConnection failed to start successfully because of error 'Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error. ArgumentNullException: IDX10000: The parameter 'token' cannot be a 'null' or an empty object. (Parameter 'token')'.

```
final hubProtLogger = Logger("SignalR - hub");

hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(ApisUrls.baseUrl+"/ChatHub?clientId=${userProfile.userId}", options: HttpConnectionOptions(
    accessTokenFactory: () async => await headerHelper.gettokenWithoutBearer()
)
).withAutomaticReconnect().configureLogging(hubProtLogger).build();

hubConnection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 30000;
if (hubConnection.state != HubConnectionState.Connected) {
  await hubConnection.start();
  print('${hubConnection.connectionId}');
  setState(() {

  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: [This repo](https://github.com/mehdi-nemati/flutter-chat-signalr) can help you

Comment: @Mehdi sir how can send notification by cliend id or userId by using flutter and asp.net?

Comment: Add user to group  => await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupename);  -- 

groupname can be your userId  --

Send message to user by group => await Clients.Group(groupname).SendAsync(<your data>);  --  

get userId => Context.UserIdentifier;